# Location of compiled java files in OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, google-app-engine

I'm using Eclipse Juno release with Google App Engine SDK.

I'm trying to find the location of the compiled java files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy your app to Google App Engine, then look at the logs to determine the staging directory.

> ------------ Deploying frontend ------------
>
> Preparing to deploy:  Created staging directory at:
>   '/var/folders/ws/jfsjfe34094fsfk_qy4l505353fs/T/appcfg2472932957495.tmp'

Then go to eclipse, run the local development server, and make sure you use/visit the JSP page that you want to look at.

Then go to `/var/folders/ws/jfsjfe34094fsfk_qy4l505353fs/T/` (this directory is just one level higher from the staging directory that was created earlier).

You should see a directory similar to this: `Jetty_127_0_0_1_8888_war____.g1qk12`. Go into the directory, go down further, and you should see your compiled JSP files!